# using the ruby gem, how can I connect to indexdepot elasticsearch instance?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

The uri for my elatsticsearch index on indexdepot is:

```
'http://xxx:xxx@www.indexdepot.com/elasticsearch/954dc1d4a0fddcf6/'
```

The port is 80.

So I have tried the following:

```
require "elasticsearch"
require "elasticsearch/transport"
require "json"

    Elasticsearch::Client.new host: 'http://xxx:xxx@www.indexdepot.com/elasticsearch/954dc1d4a0fddcf6:80'
    client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
    jsondata = {first:"mari", last:"saga", email:"mari@operamail.com",  password:"sugar"}
    client.index  index: 'swiss_candidates', type: 'users', body: jsondata
```

and the error message is:

```
[Faraday::ConnectionFailed] Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 {:host=>"localhost", :port=>"9200", :protocol=>"http"}
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
```

What's going on here? it seems as if it is trying to make a local connection. At the moment, I am trying to connect from my local machine rather than a remote website, is that relevant? All help gratefully received. Thank you.

Comment: it should be not `host` but `url` and :80 port must be just after the domain name

Comment: thanks, at first go it does not work. I will experiment.